# Remove a value from a querystring Part 2

Tags: php, html, xhtml

Expanding on my original question [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233636/remove-a-value-from-a-querystring) I would now like to remove more than 1 variable from the querystring.

For example, I want to remove the variables `bar1` & `bar2` from the querystring. I have tried the following code:

```
echo parseQueryString("http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"bar2","bar1");
```

But this doesn't remove both variables, only `bar2`.

Any help appreciated.

Thank you,

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be wanting something like

```
echo parseQueryString(parseQueryString("http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"bar2"),"bar1");
```

Alternatively, since I'm assuming parseQueryString is a function you defined, you can change it so it accepts an array argument and loops over the array.

Answer (score 3):

I would use

- `parse_str($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"], $array);` to take apart the query string
- `unset($array["bar1"]);` to remove the unwanted variables
- `http_build_query($array);` to glue the query string back together

Answer (score 1):

I have created a new function which works with multiple parameters.

```
<?php
function parseQueryString($url,$remove_arr) {
    $infos=parse_url($url);
    $str=$infos["query"];
    $op = array();
    $pairs = explode("&", $str);
    foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
       list($k, $v) = array_map("urldecode", explode("=", $pair));
        $op[$k] = $v;
    }
    foreach($remove_arr as $remove){
        if(isset($op[$remove])){
            unset($op[$remove]);
        }
    }

    return str_replace($str,http_build_query($op),$url);

} 
echo parseQueryString("http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],array("bar2","bar1"));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `parseQueryString` function will work for query strings with array components such as `&bar[]=5&bar[]=12` etc. I think all but one would be dropped from the result.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for posting. Unfortunately, this doesn't really answer the question. Please have a look at [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).